# How To Include Additional Software In preseed.cfg For Ubuntu Server 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, preseed, ubuntu-13.04, juju

I am doing fully automated installation of Ubuntu Server (Saucy) 13.10 and also wants to include custom additional softwares,The Format of preseed.cfg is:

```
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US
d-i debian-installer/language string en
d-i debian-installer/country string NL
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_GB.UTF-8
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/modelcode string pc105
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string us
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
d-i netcfg/dhcp_failed note
d-i netcfg/dhcp_options select Configure network manually
d-i netcfg/get_nameservers string 192.168.1.1
d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string 192.168.1.42
d-i netcfg/get_netmask string 255.255.255.0
d-i netcfg/get_gateway string 192.168.1.1
d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string demo
d-i netcfg/get_domain string www.demo.com
d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string archive.ubuntu.com
d-i mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
d-i mirror/http/mirror select CC.archive.ubuntu.com
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i time/zone string US/Eastern
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true
d-i clock-setup/ntp-server string ntp.example.com
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-md/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i passwd/user-fullname string demo
d-i passwd/username string demo
d-i passwd/user-password password demo123
d-i passwd/user-password-again password demo123
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect ubuntu-desktop
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server build-essential juju ruby virtualbox kvm git openstack
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select none
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
```

I tried to include custom softwares juju,openstack by write them in the end of %post, 
By this way:

```
%post
juju
git
openstack
ruby
```

But i got parsing error, Now i tried to include those softwares in pkgsel/include but again got error, Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `pkgsel/include` is the correct way to do this.  What error did you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead to use pkgsel/include i used late command, pkgsel will work if those packages listed in Ubuntu repository, But as desired packages not included in Ubuntu official repo, pkgsel would not work, So better to use late command.

Comment: do you mind to tell was what is `late command` ?

Answer (score 0):

"%post" is used to run post install commands.  Instead of "%post" you want to use "%packages":

```
%packages
juju
git
openstack
ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following in the preseed config script.

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
                in-target apt-get install <packages>
```

Comment: why this is downvoted. It's a good answer. Do not abuse your ability to click downvote. one question about this is ... shouldn't we use -y to silent the installation ?